# Jquery UI validation error on datepicker date format is always triggered in French

Tags: jquery-ui, validation, format, multilingual, globalization

I have a form with a date field. This is how it looks it the Razor view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TargetDate, string.Format("{0:D}", Model.TargetDate),      new { @class = "datePicker" })
```

In my JS file, this is how I declare the datepicker:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional[Globalize.culture().language]);
$(".datePicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: Globalize.culture().language == "en" ? "DD, MM dd, yy" : "DD dd MM yy",
});
```

As you can see, the application is multilingual.

When I load the view, the date is displayed properly in the field. But when I try to change the date or submit the form when the application is set in French, a validation error is triggered. This is the generated HTML:

```
<input class="datePicker hasDatepicker input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field TargetDate must be a date." name="TargetDate" type="text" value="mercredi 16 avril 2014" id="dp1396482596956">
```

It works well with English.

I'm using the Globalization package along with Jquery-2.1.0 and Jquery-ui-1.10.1.

Any idea on what's causing the validation think it's the wrong format?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any solution to fix the validation so I made a workaround: I added one textbox. The first textbox contains the datepicker date formatted and localized and is not mapped to the viewmodel so validation will be ok. The datepicker updates the second field that is invisible and mapped to the viewmodel with a standard format.

I added an EditorTemplate to my view.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TargetDate, "GoalTargetDate")
```

And this is what my GoalTargetDate.cshtml looks like

```
@model DateTime?

<span class="date setDate @(Model.HasValue ? string.Empty : "noDisplay")">
@Language.Goals.By    
<input class="datePicker" value="@(Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("D") : string.Empty)" />    
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model, Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : null, new { @class = "dateValue noDisplay" })
</span>

<span class="date addDate @(Model.HasValue ? "noDisplay" : string.Empty)">Add date</span>
```

And this is the Jquery code for the datepicker (I have many datepickers in my page)

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional[Globalize.culture().language]);
$(".datePicker").each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker({
        dateFormat: Globalize.culture().language == "en" ? "DD, MM dd, yy" : "DD dd MM yy",
        altField: $(this).closest(".setDate").find(".dateValue"),
        altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
});
```